# RavenDb using Include for single Db request with LoadAsync

Tags: c#, async-await, ravendb

I'm trying to have RavenDb perform a single request by using .Include() however I get multiple requests when using the async methods.

```
public class List
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }           
    public List<string> Items { get; set; }                
}

public class ListItem
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }           
}
```

*List.Items is a collection of Id's referencing Item documents.*

### 1. Sync Approach - single request

```
var session = store.OpenSession();
var listId = new Guid("181aaacd-6505-4a49-96a8-c2da5abb426a");
var list = session.Include<List, ListItem>(bp => bp.Items).Load<List>(listId);
return session.Load<ListItem>(list.Items);
```

which correctly gives

`Request # 412: GET     -     2 ms - listdb - 304 - /queries/?&include=Items(Item/)&id=Lists%2181aaacd-6505-4a49-96a8-c2da5abb426a`

---

### 2. Async Approach - multiple requests**

```
var session = store.OpenAsyncSession();
var listId = new Guid("181aaacd-6505-4a49-96a8-c2da5abb426a");
var list = await session.Include<List, ListItem>(l => l.Items).LoadAsync<List>(listId);
return await session.LoadAsync<ListItem>(list.Items);
```

which generates 2 requests which is not what I'm expecting

```
Request #   1: GET     -     0 ms - listdb - 304 - /queries/?include=Items(Item/)&id=Lists%22181aaacd-6505-4a49-96a8-c2da5abb426a
Request #   2: GET     -     0 ms - listdb - 304 - /queries/?&id=Items%2F3d75a8d6-a12d-4dd7-8c35-4e093a66adaa
```

Is this expected?
Async issue?

Raven Build 2951, Version 2.5.0 / 6dce79a

Comment: That isn't expected. Please post an issue with a repro on issues.hibernatingrhinos.com

Comment: Hi Oren.. sure the issue is here: http://issues.hibernatingrhinos.com/issue/RavenDB-3619

Comment: Working on it, will report there.